# How can I synchronize column sorting across 2 Angular UI-Grids

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angular-directive, angular-ui-grid

I want to display 2 grids to the user that will generally have the same exact data which the users will be able to verify. What I'm worried about is that the users will change the sort order of one grid without changing the other, leading to the false impression that the grids do not match.

How can I synchronize the sorting of the grids such that when the user changes the sort order of a column on one grid, it is automatically sorted on the other.?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to just setup the useExternalSorting value and the sortInfo and put a watch on sortInfo. If you use the same sortInfo for both grids, changin it in either place should trigger your watch and you'll have to do the sorting yourself.